# Unable to start Windows firefox from WSL2

Tags: firefox, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, jupyter-notebook

I'm running WSL2 on a windows 10 machine. WSL2 is supposed to support calling windows executables. This works for programs like notepad. However, when trying to run firefox I run into a few issues.

If I add the program's directory to my path with:

`export PATH="${PATH}:/mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Mozilla\ Firefox"`

followed by a call to `firefox.exe`, it doesn't find the exe and I get

> firefox.exe: command not found

If instead I add it to my path with
`export PATH="${PATH}:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/"`

and then call `firefox.exe`, or if I try to run it by calling the full path of the executable (here it needs the backslashes):

`/mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Mozilla\ Firefox/firefox.exe`

I get a [Windows error dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlEOD.png):

> Windows cannot find
> 'shell:appsFolder\MicrosoftCorporationII.WindowsSubsystemForLinux_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App'. Make sure you've typed the name correctly, then try again.

The reason I want to call Windows Firefox from WSL is because I'm running TensorFlow in a Jupyter notebook with JupyterLab, so I need WSL/Jupyterlab to be able to call my host Windows system browser to open the notebook page when I start JupyterLab, as per how it behaves if you start JupyterLab normally on Windows. Since TensorFlow dropped support for native Windows, I'm using TensorFlow via WSL2 as per [TensorFlow's guidance](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip).

The only workaround I've found for now is to manually copy the URL from the console when JupyterLab and paste it into my Windows Firefox browser.

Comment: WSL2 does support calling windows executables, but graphical apps require Windows 11, or the installation of an X server in Windows.

Comment: @harrymc As I said at the start of the post, calling Windows Notepad (a graphical app) from WSL2 works.
I'm not trying to run a GUI app installed within the Linux distro on my WSL2; I'm trying to make a call to the host Windows system to tell it to open an app installed on it.

Comment: Not familiar with WSL, but I wonder if perhaps the PATH you need to mess with is the one on the Windows side instead of the one in WSL/bash.

Comment: @harrymc - "graphical apps require Windows 11" - WSLg was backported to Windows 10. What the author should probably do is install Firefox within WSL instead.

Comment: @TomYan - I doubt that would work if TensorFlow/Jupyterlab requires a browser. Expecting the ability for TensorFlow installed within WSL to be able to use a browser installed on Windows is unrealistic.

Comment: Try this syntax : `"/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla/Firefox/firefox.exe"`. For my Firefox installation this worked: `"/mnt/c/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"`.

Comment: @harrymc I tried this syntax and get the same Windows error dialogue box as in the post.

I've also now tried a fresh reinstall of  (64-bit) Firefox in Program Files (rather than the x86 directory where my Firefox install was previously living) just in case, but still get the same windows error message with the equivalent syntax pointing at the fresh reinstall.

Comment: Are Windows *and* WSL2 fully updated?

Comment: A couple of questions - (1) Are you using Ubuntu or another distribution?  I just want to make sure I test any possible answer on the right distribution. (2) Are you getting that Windows dialog/error *just* running `"/mnt/c/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"`, or does that happen when you are trying to open your Jupyter notebook?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds (1) I'm using Ubuntu yes. (2) Yes I get the dialogue/error running `"/mnt/c/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"`. I also get the same dialogue/error upon starting JupyterLab if I first set the `c.ServerApp.browser` variable to point at the browser as per this [StackExchange answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47793764).

Comment: I've updated the original post as I've now fixed the issue and even got WSL2 Ubuntu JupyterLab to open automatically in my Windows Firefox!

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the help!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Tom Yan Thanks for the help! (I wish they'd let you at-mention multiple users in a comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Moved this information from the user's edited question into a Community answer:*

Since making this post, I've installed the following Windows 10 updates via windows update:

- KB4023057
- KB5030180
- KB5030211

I'm pleased to report calling Firefox from within Ubuntu on WSL2 with the syntax

`"/mnt/c/Program Files/Mozilla/Firefox/firefox.exe"`

now successfully opens my Windows Firefox without the error dialogue box in the original post below.

I'd previously believed my Windows install was up-to-date, as clicking the big `Check for updates` button just came back with "You're up to date", as per the below screenshot. However, upon clicking the `Check online for update from Microsoft Update` (also pictured) these three new updates appeared.

[image: Windows update screenshot]

As for JupyterLab, in order to get it to open in Windows Firefox, I added/set the following in my `jupyter_server_config.py` file (see answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772157/how-to-change-the-default-browser-used-by-jupyter-notebook-in-windows) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756151/how-to-set-jupyter-notebook-to-open-on-browser-automatically)):

```
c.ServerApp.browser = u'/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Mozilla\ Firefox/firefox.exe %s'
c.ServerApp.use_redirect_file = False
```